# how to retrieve image which stored in cloud

Tags: android, cloud

image stored in cloud "https://www1.copy.com/home/ganesh.jpg" on this link ..and i am not able to get image in application

```
public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;

    // Imageview to show
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Image url
    String image_url = "https://www.copy.com/browse/copy/0017.JPG";

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Problem :

The link https://www1.copy.com/home/ganesh.jpg doenst return an image.
maybe you you need to login to the site and then you can get the image.

Solution :

Try ot get the srouce code of the ImageLoader jar and try to modify the URLConnection and pass the credentials to log in to the site.